# How to make CustomRadioButton with 8 options in 2 rows

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm trying to create a CustomRadioButton that have 8 options to be in 2 rows, each row has 4 buttons that fit the screen width without any scrolling.

my current code is as follows:

```
Row(
          children: [
            CustomRadioButton(
              elevation: 0,
              absoluteZeroSpacing: true,
              unSelectedColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
              buttonLables: [
                '1',
                '2',
                '3',
                '4',
                '5',
                '6',
                '7',
                '8',

              ],
              buttonValues: [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4",
                "5",
                "6",
                "7",
                "8",

              ],
              buttonTextStyle: ButtonTextStyle(
                  selectedColor: Colors.white,
                  unSelectedColor: Colors.black,

                  textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
              radioButtonValue: (value) {
                print(value);
              },
              height: 50,
              selectedColor: Colors.red,
            ),

          ],
        ),
```

Now the 8 options are in one row.
How i can achieve this?

Comment: Please include code of `CustomRadioButton` to let us know what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Inplace of Row use a Wrap widget. It will move down the widgets that overflows from the screen

```
Wrap(
          children: [
            CustomRadioButton(
              elevation: 0,
              absoluteZeroSpacing: true,
              unSelectedColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
              buttonLables: [
                '1',
                '2',
                '3',
                '4',
                '5',
                '6',
                '7',
                '8',

              ],
              buttonValues: [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4",
                "5",
                "6",
                "7",
                "8",

              ],
              buttonTextStyle: ButtonTextStyle(
                  selectedColor: Colors.white,
                  unSelectedColor: Colors.black,

                  textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
              radioButtonValue: (value) {
                print(value);
              },
              height: 50,
              selectedColor: Colors.red,
            ),

          ],
        ),
```

Same applies for CustomRadioButton. If you have returned a row please replace it with a wrap..

If its not overflowing but you still wish to keep 4 items in a row. You can try taking a look at gridview